# Calculate surface area size of OpenCV-contour?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a function which finds contours within a scanned image using function

```
   cv::findContours(*srcImg,contours,cv::RETR_LIST,cv::CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS);
```

This works well...or ot be exact, it works way too good. So the function also finds several contours which are not the contours I would like to find but some noise/dust spots on the scanned image.

So my idea is to check the size of all contours returned, calculate the average and then drop all contours which are far below of this average.

So my question: how can I calculate the surface area size of such a contour returned as

```
std::vector<cv::Point>
```

?

Or is there a better approach to get rid of noise in this image?

Thank you!

Comment: Blurring the image (e.g. GaussianBlur) before `findContours `would help filter out small contours due to noises. Thresholding the contours by size, e.g. `contourArea` is helpful as well.

Comment: @QuangHoang blurring makes it even worse because the noises become bigger. Thresholding the contours is not an approach for me as I do not know the size of them in advance - I only cna try to find out what size they have in the particular image _after_ I have detected them - that's why I had the idea with the average surface size of all contours...

Comment: @Elmi please share the images

Comment: you've already been given the answer you want: `contourArea`. however I would recommend that you use `connectedComponentsWithStats`, unless you _actually_ need the contours for something. connected components labeling is _exact_ and a lot more convenient for erasing blobs. -- did you truly not find any results for "opencv contour area"?